# Customer's logo as a default bootanimation

Tags: android, linux, boot-animation

I am developing an android customized os for a customer. What I am trying to do is change the custom bootanimation to customer's bootanimation logo. In u-boot i have changed it but in android and in kerel I do not know how to do it. 
I have two default images

```
android-logo-mask.png
android-logo-shine.png
```

What I am thinking is if I change my logo with same resolution and same name it will be displayed. But I need to change the size and many other things for the customer. There is a file Bootanimation.cpp in frameworks/base/cmds/bootanimation but I am not able to change the height, width and background of the android-logo-mask.png. 
What can be the possible change I can do in this file to acheive proper image control?

I want to make my customer's logo as a default bootanimation.?

Comment: search for bootanimation.zip - I think there is a sequence of png files in there that are the same resolution as the entire screen. If you change the images in there, then the boot animation changes - see this: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/change-android-boot-animation/

Comment: I know what you are telling, but can't we just change the default animation to ours, instead of creating bootanimation.zip from outside.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure you can, sorry, that's all I know.. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can replace logo_linux_clut224.ppm with your logo before building the kernel.
this file is in /KERNEL/drivers/video/logo

find more about android boot animation here:
https://code.google.com/p/custom-android-sciphone-n19/wiki/BootAnimation